# What does "I am off to the doctor" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

In [this video](https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=371890786336564&permPage=1) a well-known man says

> I am off to the doctor.

I think it means **I am going to visit my doctor**. However another rendering occurred to me; can it mean **I am not at work due to the order of my doctor**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the first definition [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/off):

> Away from the place in question
>
> *the man ran off*
>
> *she dashed off to her room*
>
> *we must be off now*

So you could say:

> I am leaving [here] for the doctor['s office].

*I'm off* emphasizes a bit more that the speaker is **leaving** wherever they currently are while *going* is more generally stating that you're heading in that direction.

---

> can it mean **I am not at work due to the order of my doctor?**

No.  It would never mean this.

Comment: I'm off (this place/here as I'm going) to the doctor. An elliptical structure typical for spoken language where self-evident things are dropped.